# Facebook Callback when application is removed from page

Tags: php, facebook

I'm currently on working on creating an app that added to facebook page's tab. The documentation is here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

But the documentation mentions nothing about a callback for the application is removed. Is there a such callback that will alert me when my application is removed a tab that I can use to update my records?

If it matters, I'm currently using PHP.

Comment: No, there is no such callback. What are you actually trying to achieve, what kind of data do you want _updated_ when this happens?

Comment: I store the ID of the page in a database an associate it with an app. I am trying to remove that ID if the app is removed from the tab.

Comment: Is this really important for your workflow though, or are you just trying to “save space”? The latter would not be that important, I’s guess.

Comment: Its to keep track of data, ideally to say "this app is currently being used in 30 pages".

Answer (score 3):

Go to your app: Admin page -> Edit settings -> advanced then Deauthorize Callback URL

Here is a php example on how I deauthorize a user in my code:

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/autoload.php');
App::init();
DBConn::init();
error_log("request");

$app_secret = 'yoursecretkey';
$request = parse_signed_request($_POST['signed_request'], $app_secret);
$fbid=$request["user_id"];
error_log($fbid);
if ($fbid) {
    $rec = new ADOdb_Active_Record( "users" );
    $found=$rec->load("id=?",array($fbid));
    if ($found){
        $rec->deauth= 1;
        $rec->save();
    }
}
echo "ok";

function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

    // decode the data
    $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
    }

    // check sig
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }

    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

Comment: Ha so your right, Dunno how I didn't see that both in the document and the UI +1

Comment: In my experience the deauthorize callback is invoked when an app is removed by a user, but I have never seen it hit when a page manager removes an app's tab from their page.  I believe this is an incorrect answer for the narrow case of this question focused on removing a tab.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such a callback only one for if the user cancels giving your app the privileges first time around.

When you try to auth the user next time on your site and the auth does not succeed then you know they have either:

- Deauthed your app
- Or the fb token has not been used for 60 days

As such the users should reauth your app.

Edit: By site I do mean app. English Fail.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you can find such a callback why don't you place an answer?

Comment: true, there is not a callback for remove from tab notification, only for app removal , that is the deauthorize callback as per documentation

Comment: @luca Really? So when the user removes the app from their app section there is a callback? Can you show the documentation page for that?